# Find $x$ in a geometry problem involving isoceles triangles (figure attached)

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Find x (in degrees) from the figure below. Triangles ABE and BCD are isoceles, with bases AE (**originally typed as AB, by mistake**) and CD, respectively.

[image: Figure 1]

This problem is from a math olympiad contest, the answer stated is x=15 degrees,  but the solution is not available and I'm not sure it is correct. Not able to find a starting point after some hard thinking. Please help. Sorry if it was answered before, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Edit: As others pointed out, in comments and in the answer, the solution for $x$ is not unique. See below for details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure something is missing from the statement. I can construct an quadrilateral in geogebra which fit your description with $x$ differs from $15^\circ$.

Comment: Yes! We need some given else.

Comment: I've double checked the problem statement, that is in a book with a collection of problems from previous olympiad contests. The answer stated there (x=15) maybe wrong.

Comment: There is nothing specialy said for $E$. Sure there is missing information? Prehaps $BE$ is angle bisector of  $\angle DBC$?

Comment: @johnnobody: no other information was provided.

Comment: Which book? What year is the contest? What is the actual statement that appear on book. If you add those info to your question, someone may actually dig out the original question.

Comment: In the figure only $2x$ and $4x$ are used. I would normally expect that to be $x$ and $2x$ rather than pointlessly doubled. So is there some angle in the picture that is supposed to be $x$?

Comment: Original question (in Spanish, from a Peruvian Book, from the early 80s, in the pdf I have there are no front pages): "En el seguinte gráfico, los triângulos ABE y BCD son isóceles de bases AE y CD respectivamente. Halle x." The figure is the exact picture that appears in the book. No specific mention to from which olympiad it was taken.

Comment: I´ve just spoted a typo in my original question, compared to this.... the base is from the first is AE and not AB as originally typed (will fix). Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: Even with this correction, any value for $x$ is possible (provided $4x<90°$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ can be any angle in $(0, 45°)$. The triangle $B A D$ must be a right triangle at $A$. Take any right triangle, take any straight line $L$ with angle $2x$ with $A D$, then let $C$ be the intersection point between $L$ and the circle ${\cal C}(B, B D)$, let $E$ be the intersection of $L$ and the line segment bissector of $A B$ and you have the figure.